# How to create a custom asp.net identity provider with SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

The scenario I have is the following, I am going to create a software as a service application hosted in azure, where all users will be able to login with a username and password, the SQL identity provider seems a good option but I need something custom.

The software would be like an accounting system, and one accountant can manage multiple companies, the idea is that once the user is logged in, the provider should return also the list of companies he has right to.

Once logged in, the idea is to show the user a dashboard of the companies he can manage the accounting to.

However I am not sure what should I be looking for.  I am not an OAUTH expert, but we should use OAUTH, I suppose there should be a way to return a token/claim with the list of companies the user has access to after logging in

I cant paste some code, as I dont have the starting point yet 
Thanks a lot

Comment: valid question shame on the -1

Comment: What have you tried? What have you investigated? And how "custom" do you need the provider to be?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can implement a custom membership provider by inheriting base MembershipProvider class and implementing your custom login logic.

Maybe this blog should be able to guide you.
[Creating Custom Membership Provide](http://technobird.blogspot.com.au/2010/04/creating-custom-membership-provider-for.html)

While ASP.NET Identity is the new way to do things WCF internally still uses ASP.NET Membership Provider and it works well. There is nothing wrong with both approach.

Comment: `MembershipProvider` is long depricated and should not be used in new projects. Asp.Net Identity have replaced the old framework.